# Network not working after network-manager disabled

Tags: networking, network-manager, kvm-virtualization

I'm using the Wok web interface to manage a kvm virtual machine. Wok would not allow a bridged vm interface with network-manager enabled, so I disabled it. Since then networking does not work on the host (everything was working before). IP address is configured properly and routing table shows correct routes. The host can ping itself, but no other hosts on the LAN. I tried

```
sudo service networking restart
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network restart
```

and

```
ifdown eno1

ifup eno1
```

and multiple reboots, no success.

Here is the network setup:

```
me@host:~$ ip address show eno1 | grep 192

    inet 192.168.1.201/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic eno1

me@host:~$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno1

169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1

192.168.122.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: How did you ' disable ' it? Or did you mean you restarted the Service?

Comment: I disabled it using 'sudo service network-manager stop'. Turns out network-manager was not the problem though. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkManager was not the problem. I had configured KVM to use a bridge network, which took control of eno1 and prevented it from communicating on the LAN. Here's /etc/network/interfaces after enabling the bridge network. I commented out the lines 'auto kbeno1','iface kbeno1 inet manual', and 'bridge-ports eno1'. Now the host can talk on the LAN again.

///interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto kbeno1

iface kbeno1 inet manual

```
  bridge_ports eno1
```

auto eno1

iface eno1 inet static

```
  address 192.168.1.201

  netmask 255.255.255.0

  gateway 192.168.1.1

  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```